# Rebuilding a day's stats?

Tags: matomo

I have a peculiar problem. Piwik normally mostly-works on my DreamHost installation of it (I'll be moving it later, but until then..), but we got hit pretty hard the last few days.

Specifically, it was bad enough that this happened:

[image: 0 hits on a particular day]

(To be specific, the day with 0 is wrong; it was at least 30,000 before it turned into 0. The next day is just leftovers from the initial spike and is normal.)

Is there any way to rebuild the stats for a specific day, or is the only way to rebuild everything?

Comment: I have no idea what happened but a few days later it magically fixed itself on its own. I don't think that's a good solution, though, so I'm not answering this with "just wait a while and pray".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the FAQ [How do I force the reports to be re-processed from the logs?](https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_59/) there are several methods.

You can drop the tables `piwik_archive_blob_YYYY_MM` and `piwik_archive_numeric_YYYY_MM` containing the date you want to be rearchived. This is the method I had used.

Alternatively you can temporarily add:

```
[Debug]
always_archive_data_day = 1
```

to your `config/config.ini.php` to force archiving of daily reports.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting archive table as well as changing the config are an overkill in this case (you will reprocess more data than you need).

The easiest solution is to invalidate this day. Here you have the faq entry:
http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_155/